# mySQL within Python 2.7.9

Tags: python, mysql, linux, python-2.7

Arrghh...  I am trying to use mySQL with Python.  I have installed all the libraries for using mySQL, but keep getting the: "ImportError: No module named mysql.connector" for "import mysql.connector", "mysql", etc..

Here is my config:

I have a RHEL server:

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)

with Python 2.7.9

> Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 16 2014, 10:42:10) 
>   [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2

with mySQL 5.1

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

---

I have all the appropriate libraries/modules installed, I think!

yum install MySQL-python

> Package MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.3.c1.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version

yum install mysql-connector-python.noarch

> Installed: mysql-connector-python.noarch 0:1.1.6-1.el6
>   yum install MySQL-python.x86_64
>   Package MySQL-python-1.2.3-0.3.c1.1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version

yum install mysql-connector-python.noarch

> Package mysql-connector-python-1.1.6-1.el6.noarch already installed and latest version

---

What am I doing wrong?  HELP!?

Comment: Are you developing in a `Virtual Enviroment`
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/
If not you are running the risk of having an unorganized system, your environment may not be looking in the right place for your python modules

Comment: what you see when you do `import MySQLdb`

Comment: @Vor:  I am not using MySQLdb.  I am/want to use the mysql.connector from Oracle/mySQL.  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=457183

Comment: @DanHabib:  Honestly .. I have never heard of a "Virtual Environment" in regards to Python.  I just have a basic Linux environment, I have used YUM for all installs, and this has worked in the past.. "driving" my driver batty! :(

Comment: @Vor:  >>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

Comment: @jewettg there is an easy process involved with setting up a virtual environment, but the benefits gained from learning how to work in one are powerful. For starters everything will behave as expected since there aren't any outside programs or environments in play. Also it makes it very easy to recreate your environment on another machine if neccesary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `virtualenv` in order to isolate the environment. That way your project libs won't clash with other projects libs. Also, you probably should install the `Mysql` driver/connector from `pip`.

`Virtualenv` is a CLI tool for managing your environment. It is really easy to use and helps a lot. What it does is to create all the folders Python needs on a custom location (usually your specific project folder) and it also sets all the shell variables so that Python can find the folders. Your system (/usr and so on) folders are not removed from the shell; rather, they just get a low priority. That is done by correctly setting your `PATH` variable, and `virtualenv` does that when you load a determined environment.

It is common practice to use an environment for each project you work on. That way, Python and `pip` won't install libs on the global folders. Instead, `pip` installs the libs on the current environment you are using. That avoids version conflicts and even Python version conflicts.

Comment: @canouro:  What is a virtual environment regarding Python?  I am going to Google it now, but is this just adding more complexity to my setup?  See comment above?

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind!!!

Apparently I am installing Python and libraries in the right directories and such (I have always used YUM), but apparently there are other versions of Python installed.. need to clean that up.

> Running: /usr/bin/python
>
> All the modules worked!
>
> Running: python (Linux finding python in the path somewhere)
>
> Modules are not working!

Grrr...

Maybe I will checking out the Python "Virtual Environments"!
Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Having a `Virtualenv` would allow you to control which version of python is installed. And if you mess things up in a virtual environment it is very easy to tear it down and create a new one